# AWS CodeDeploy skipping all instances while AS terminates a instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, autoscaling

We have a AWS CodeDeploy set up in our AWS environment.

Yesterday, while CodeDeploy was deploying the code on all the instances, one of the instances got terminated by the AutoScaling group and because of that our deployment got failed on that instances and codedeploy skipped all the instances after that.

How do I make sure if the deployment gets failed on one instance, CodeDeploy doesn't skip deployment on all other instances?

[image: aws-codedeploy-error]